# Bash string manipulation regex or string indexing

Tags: regex, bash

I have two possible artifacts, which I need to modify with a basch script.
Artifacts before manipulation are following

- tesla-server-1.1.1-develop#34.tgz
- tesla-server-1.1.1-master#34.tgz

After I run my regex on them, they should look the following

- tesla-server-1.1.1-develop.tgz
- tesla-server-1.1.1.tgz

What I have is the following

```
#!/bin/env bash

branch=master or develop

if [[ "${branch}" == "develop" ]]; then
  artifact="tesla-server-1.1.1-develop#34.tgz"
  new_artifact `expr match "$artifact" '(.+develop|.tgz)'`
  cp artifact new_artifact
elif [[ "${branch}" == "master" ]]; then
  artifact="tesla-server-1.1.1-master#34.tgz"
  new_artifact `expr match "$artifact" '(.+master|.tgz)'`
  cp artifact new_artifact
fi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, either using `regex` og `string indexing`

Comment: you can do a regex rename using the rename command.. man rename for examples..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do:

```
file='tesla-server-1.1.1-master#34.tgz'

cp "$file" $(sed -E 's/(-master)?#[0-9]+//' <<< "$file")
```

This will copy given file to `tesla-server-1.1.1.tgz`

Comment: excellent answer, but what about the develop branch, how do acchive to include there `develop` name in the file name?

Comment: This same sed command will copy `tesla-server-1.1.1-develop#34.tgz` to `tesla-server-1.1.1-develop.tgz`